# Devise and Client_side_validation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi i use the Devise gem and want to use Client_side_validation
i install gem and put

```
//= require rails.validations
```

in to my assets/javasctipt/application.js

and in the form i add

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true ) do |f| %>
```

I thought thats all i need to do ... 
but when i unfocus my fild - nothing happens ( i got one warning in my fire bug ) ->

```
TypeError: settings is undefined
 .live('focusout', function() { $(this).isValid(settings.validators); })
```

does not work
where i have mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue, investigating.

On my side, it seems that the js exported by client-side-validation, which in my case is
    `window['user_new']`
doesn't match the id of the form
    `new_user`

So when rails.validation.js try to get the data
    `var settings = window[form.attr('id')];`
it fails.

[EDIT]

In the devise view, replacing

```
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true) do |f|
```

by

```
= form_for(resource, :validate => true) do |f|
```

fixes it for me!

Not really sure why the `:as => resource_name` invert the name of the resource though ?

Comment: = form_for(resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true) do |f|    =>  
that is right string - what i need!  => thanks man =))))))

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? 3.2.0.beta.4 fixed this for me, corresponding github issue [here](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/pull/343).

Comment: gem 'client_side_validations'  without any versions